# How do I change the function of my keys on my keyboard?

Tags: windows-7

I just bought a new laptop and I would really like to change the function of two of the keys. One is the play button at the top when there is no music player up it automatically brings up windows media player and I would like it to bring up itunes, also I have a button that looks like 3 little guys laughing and it brings up Social Network and I would like it to bring up MSN. I have tried SharpKeys, Key Tweak and Autohotkey but it didn’t recognize my keys. What else can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a multi-media laptop. Most of the time you can remap the keys with a utility provided by the manufacturer of the laptop. Usually you will find the program under a folder named after the manufacturer like C:\HP or C:\TOSHIBA. You may be able to find the name of the utility in the Task Manager, look for something like kbd.exe then use the Seach feature of Windows to find the utility.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [KeyTweak](http://webpages.charter.net/krumsick/).  This little program is a front-end that will allow you to remap all of the keys on your keyboard.  It has a simple interface, and the ability to even teach remapping by pressing the keys that need remapped to a particular button.

Note:  This utility will not let you remap the "Fn" key on your laptop since these keystrokes are read by the bios, not by Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remap them to something else with another program, as I believe the key is a hardware for what key-code they keyboard will send.

You might be able to change the default media player in windows.

Or there might be a gateway program that will allow you to edit what they key presses will open.

If all else fails, use a shortcut editor and use completely different keys to achieve your goals.